# HttpURLConnection unable to capture HTTP 302 correctly in a Java test

Tags: java, junit, httpurlconnection, http-redirect, http-status-code-302

I am trying to write a test for a URL /rdrct which redirects to another URL, say /test on the same host. On the application, the redirect works fine and I see a HTTP 302 in the Network Inspector but when I write a Java test, it fails and I get the following error.

**expected: <200> but was: <302>**

```
@Test
public void testRedirect() throws Exception { 
    String uri = "http://localhost:" + port + "/rdrct";
    URL url = new URL(uri);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,"
        + "image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7");
    connection.connect();
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    assertEquals(responseCode, 302); 
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Minor point, the first argument to `assertEquals` should be the expected value, which would make the message say what it should.

Comment: And I think the answer to your question is that the redirect is being followed, and `/test` returns a 200 status.

Comment: 200 is "ok" 302 is a little more odd but for some , the same as 200 re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302

Comment: @SamuelMarchant No it isn't. 302 means a redirect to a URL specified in another header. 200 means success and is accompanied by the desired payload. Your source code does not support your assertion.

Comment: @OP As you are following redirects, you won't see the 302. If you want to see it, don't set the connection to follow redirects, in which case you will have to follow them yourself.

Comment: @user207421.   No it isn't his problem, he is using "assertions" , it is simply the junit test result! He "asserts the result will be 302".   (NB my other comment on return http codes infers any clear information wanted is explained in the documentation at the link). Not knowing exactly how the test is setup , "maybe he got the resource at its location". hmmmm

Comment: @SamuelMarchant they got the resource after their request followed the redirect at `/rdrct` to the actual resource at `/test`.

Comment: In that case, is there a way I can just test for the new url as /test instead and not test for http status code 302? I just need to make sure I test the redirect works